How to run ./bin/dev for Ruby on Rails from WSL
I cloned a repository which uses /bin/dev to update the changes in the code (tailwind css) dynamically without the need of asssets:recompilation.
As I am using Windows, in order to run ./bin/dev, I used WSL which leads to following error.
I installed all the necessary dependencies and libraries, also converted the dev file with dos2unix commmand.
This is the error I am facing:
> ./bin/dev
23:11:15 web.1  | started with pid 12066
23:11:15 js.1   | started with pid 12067
23:11:15 css.1  | started with pid 12079
23:11:15 web.1  | /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
23:11:15 web.1  | exited with code 127
23:11:15 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
23:11:16 js.1   | terminated by SIGTERM
23:11:16 css.1  | terminated by SIGTERM

dev file:
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if ! gem list foreman -i --silent; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

# Default to port 3000 if not specified
export PORT="${PORT:-3000}"

exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"


Procfile.dev:
web: env RUBY_DEBUG_OPEN=true bin/rails server
js: yarn build --watch
css: yarn build:css --watch



How bin/rails file looks?
